# How to kill stuck Screen sharing authentication dialogue?

Tags: performance, screen-sharing

Sometimes when connecting to a screen sharing machine in Finder, the authentication dialogue hangs indefinitely. The only way I've been able to get rid of it is log out.

So far I've tried killing a number of processes including:

- Screen Sharing
- Finder
- Dock
- SystemUIServer

To no avail. Any idea what process this UI is attached to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's called `NetAuthAgent`.

<sub>You can tell I've had this problem before! :(</sub>

Comment: +1 Yep, Me too! Mine seemed to be related with not being able to contact a remote machine via its name, e.g. mac-mini.local, only using its IP address.

Comment: Those stuck Screen Sharing auth windows have been driving me crazy forever. Thank you so much! Now if I could only get Screen sharing to actually connect reliably...